# what is laplace transform of $\sqrt{(1+\sin t)}$

Tags: laplace-transform

i don't know how to start with this question as it is under root sign. in text book answer is given as $$\frac{s}{s^2+(1/2)^2}+\frac{1/2}{s^2+(1/2)^2}$$
so from answer we can figure out that it is $$\cos(t/2)+\sin(t/2)$$ but i don't know how to transform the question in above form.

Comment: Unfortunately, under the usual interpretation of the square root, we have $$\sqrt{1 + \sin t} = \lvert \cos (t2) + \sin (t/2)\rvert,$$ and since $\cos (t/2) + \sin (t/2)$ is negative for various $t$, the given answer seems incorrect.

Comment: However, if $\sqrt{1 + \sin t}$ is to be interpreted as an analytic function $g$ such that $g(t)^2 = 1 + \sin t$ for all $t$, then it follows that $g(t) = \pm \bigl(\cos (t/2) + \sin (t/2)\bigr)$, and for the choice with $g(0) = 1$ the given Laplace transform is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same function: this is evident when you square them:

$$1+sin(t) \ \ \text{is the same as} \ \ (cos(t/2)+\sin(t/2))^2$$

Indeed, when expanded, the latter becomes: $\cos(t/2)^2+\sin(t/2)^2+2\cos(t/2)\sin(t/2)$.

and you end by applying formula $2\cos(a)\sin(a)=\sin(2a).$
We know that 1+ sint = [cos(t/2)+sin(t/2)]^2
So root of 1+ sint =cos(t/2)+sin(t/2)
Its that simple and now just apply Laplace

Answer (score 0):

Sqrt 1+sint = sqrt.(sint/2 +cost/2)^2
Which gives .(sint/2 +cost/2). As square root and square cancel out. And Laplace of (sint/2 +cost/2) will give you the answer.

Comment: You must learn basic MATHJAX. See here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference