# I need to find laplace transform for this $ℒ_t[\sqrt{\sin(2 t) + 1}]$

Tags: laplace-transform, transformation, laplace-method

if $f(t) = \sqrt{\sin(2 t) + 1}>> I$ need to solve this problem and find Laplace transform for it $( ℒ_t[f(t)] = ??)$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024303/what-is-laplace-transform-of-sqrt1-sin-t

Comment: $1+\sin2t=(\sin t+\cos t)^2$.

Comment: $$\sqrt{1+\sin(2t)}=\sqrt{1+\cos(2t-\pi/2)}=\sqrt{2\cos^2(t-\pi/4)}=\sqrt{2}|\cos(t-\pi/4)|$$

Comment: Thanks all... Very Much ♥♥♥♥♥♥♥

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $$ \sin 2t +1 = 2 \sin t \cos t + \sin^2 t + \cos ^2 t = ( \sin t + \cos t )^2$$

That takes care of the square root and the rest is easy and you can manage it.

Comment: thanks very much...♥♥♥♥♥♥

Comment: Thanks for your lovely comment.